# looking for xamarin http communication code

Tags: xamarin

i want to connect to a http server having address = http://192.168.10.1:5555/server . So can one please help me and provide some code in xamarin studio . so that i can connect to server and do some request to server.

I am connected with  server using wifi and this is my wifi code.

```
public bool isConnected()
{
    bool ret = false;
    var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
    var wifiStatelocal = connectivityManager.GetNetworkInfo(ConnectivityType.Wifi).GetState();
    if (wifiStatelocal == NetworkInfo.State.Connected) 
    {
        ret = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To communicate over http use the either [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) or [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx). Therefor you have to edit your references and add the appropriate assemblies to your project. To do this open your project and double click on the *References* folder.

If you are using a Portable Class Library (PCL) than you need to know that WebClient is not available and HttpClient need to be added as a nuGet package.

Comment: thanks ......My xamarin studio doesn't show , Many  methods and property shown in C# example supported by a particular class.i have added <b>using package_name </b> but  still it not showing.....Why?????????

Comment: I edited my answer to explain how to add references.